# Prove that a red-black tree with $n$ internal nodes has height at most $2\lg(n+1)$

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, computer-science, trees

I cannot understand the first paragraph of the proof, which comes from the known book *Introduction to Algorithms, third-edition*, and I consider it has some errors, could anyone help me check about it?

Possible errors:

1. It first prove the case $\text{height(x)=0},$ then it says "For inductive steps, consider a node $x$ that has **positive height**".

   From my understanding of inductive proof, the base case should be able to trigger the inductive statement. I mean: the "first domino" should trigger the next one, so the statement should be something like **non-negative height**.
2. It says "each child has a black-height of either $\text{bh}(x)$ or $\text{bh}(x)-1$", but when applying, only the latter is used: $(2^{\text{bh}(x)-1}-1)+(2^{\text{bh}(x)-1}-1)+1=2^{\text{bh}(x)}-1$.

---

### Paragraph from the book:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error.

1. When we consider a node $x$ of height $n$, say, in the induction step, our induction hypothesis is that the result is true for all nodes having height **less than** $n$. Thus, every node considered after the base case of height $0$ does have positive height: saying that we’re considering a node $x$ that has positive height is merely saying that we’re considering a node that isn’t part of the base case. If $x$ has height $1$, we’re just assuming the result for nodes of height $0$, and we’ve already proved that the result holds for them. If $x$ has height $2$, we’re assuming the result for nodes of height $0$ and $1$, and so on. This is just an instance of what is sometimes called [strong (or complete) induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction).
2. First, there is no harm in failing to use information if that information is not needed for the argument. However, in this case all of the information **is** used. First, we note that each child of $x$ has height less than $x$, so the induction hypothesis says that if $y$ is a child of $x$, the result is true for the subtree rooted at $y$: it contains at least $2^{\operatorname{bh}(y)}-1$ internal nodes. If $y$ is red, $\operatorname{bh}(y)=\operatorname{bh}(x)$, and the subtree rooted at $y$ contains at least $2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)}-1$ internal nodes. If $y$ is black, $\operatorname{bh}(y)=\operatorname{bh}(x)-1$, and the subtree rooted at $y$ contains at least $2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)-1}-1$ internal nodes. In all cases, therefore, the subtree rooted at $y$ contains at least $$\min\left\{2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)}-1,2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)-1}-1\right\}=2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)-1}-1$$ internal nodes, but we needed the information about both possible colors of child in order to establish this bound. We can now conclude that the subtree rooted at $x$ has at least $$\left(2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)-1}-1\right)+\left(2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)-1}-1\right)=2\cdot 2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)-1}-2=2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)}-2$$ internal nodes that are the internal nodes of the two subtrees rooted at the children of node $x$. Finally, node $x$ itself is an internal node of the subtree rooted at $x$ and is not in the subtrees rooted at the children of node $x$, so the subtree rooted at $x$ must in fact have at least $2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)}-2+1=2^{\operatorname{bh}(x)}-1$ internal nodes. This completes the induction step.